# How to send a JSON encoded string as POST param in AngularJS resource? (no field name)

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to make a POST request to an API which requires a json value. The issue is that it doesn't require a name value pair. Only a json encoded string(e.g.  `"BLK22292"`). 
Here is a snippet of the code. The issue with this is that it sends `{"": "BLK22292"}` instead of `"BLK22292"`.

```
releaseServices.factory('ObjectsList', ['$resource',
   function($resource){
   var clientID = 'BLK22292'
   var apiURL = 'https://dentals.net/apis/setClientID'
    return $resource(apiURL, {}, {
      query: {method:'POST', params:{"":clientID}, isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to build the url your self. The params object append the values as html encode params to the url (?name1=value&name2=value). In your case just append the clientId to the url.

var url = apiURL + "/" + clientID;

```
releaseServices.factory('ObjectsList', ['$resource',
   function($resource){
   var clientID = 'BLK22292'
   var apiURL = 'https://dentals.net/apis/setClientID'
   var url = apiURL + "/" + clientID;
    return $resource(url, {}, {
      query: {method:'POST', isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that's a POST and the value should be json encoded ? not sure how appending the URL helps .